# How to make my API function return "string" to Redis SETEX value

Tags: node.js, express, redis, httprequest

I am using Node.js and express.js to build a website, and call APIs in my backend

But I got little bit confused on how to make my https request return strings at the same time,

because I also need it to return stringfy JSON data to Redis SETEX function

Here is my code down below

// I am sure this works just fine

```
function myweb(para1, para2, para3, res) {

    https.get({
      hostname: 'api.com',
      path:     '/search?q=' + para1 + '&offset=' + para2 + '&filter=' + para3,
      headers:  { 'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': SUBSCRIPTION_KEY },
    }, response => {
      body = '';
      response.on('data', part => {
          body += part; 
      })
      response.on('end', () => {
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.end(JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(body)));
      })
    })
}
```

// And I got confused while trying to build up server cache

```
const redisPort = 6379;
const client = redis.createClient(redisPort);

app.get("/job", (req, res) => {
    const aaa = `${req.query.q}`;
    const bbb = `${req.query.offset}`;
    const ccc = `${req.query.filter}`;

    try {
        client.get(aaa, async (err, jobs) => {
            if (err) throw err;
    
            if (jobs) {
                return jobs;
            } else {
                const jobs = myweb(aaa, bbb, ccc, res);
                client.setex(aaa, 600, JSON.stringify(jobs));
            }
        });
    } catch(err) {
        res.status(500).send({message: err.message});
    }
  });
```

My logs told me that I try to give a undefined in third parameter of `client.setex` (which is `JSON.stringify(jobs)` )

But no matter I try, I just can't make my function `myweb` to return a proper value to SETEX...?

I think I might have some misunderstandings on https request but I am not sure...?

Please help... Thank you!

Comment: How did you solved this?

Comment: I never ;) Givr up on Redis already

Answer (score 0):

Redis saves values as strings. You need to parse the result when reading from it.

```js
client.get(aaa, async (err, jobs) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    if (jobs) {
        return JSON.parse(jobs);
    } else {
        const jobs = myweb(aaa, bbb, ccc, res)
        client.setex(aaa, 600, JSON.stringify(jobs));
    }
});
```